# Rails - Decode App Store Server Notification payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt, app-store-connect

Added Sign In with Apple support in our web application and configured App Store server to server Notification.

App Store Server sends a JSON payload encoded with JWS as notification payload as below

```
{"signedPayload":"eyJhbGciOiJF...................NLnyA"}
```

Seems like Apple does not provide public keys to decode this. As per some of the documentation, I am using AppleRootCA-G3 certificate to decode this as below:

```
apple_root_certificate_g3 = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read("AppleRootCA-G3.cer"))
apple_cert_store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new

apple_cert_store.add_cert(apple_root_certificate_g3)
notification_payload = JWT.decode(signed_payload, nil, true, {algorithm: "ES256"}) do |headers|
  cert_target, *cert_chain = headers["x5c"].map { |cert| OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(Base64.decode64(cert)) }
  apple_cert_store.verify(cert_target, cert_chain)
  cert_target.public_key
end
```

Is this correct or do we have alternate solution?

Comment: Does it decode successfully? If so that would seem to be the solution.

Comment: yes, it works as expected